# SED replace few first occurences ( and ranges ) of pattern

Tags: sed, replace, range, find-occurrences

is this possible to change first 4 ( or more ) occurences of string in this scenario using SED (opposite of `sed -r 's/[^[:space:]]*/TEST/4g'`):

```
TEST TEST TEST TEST five six seven
```

I get it working with reversing words order in line using AWK twice, but this is long, complex and I want to get this with just SED:

```
echo one two three four five six seven | awk '{for(i=NF;i>=1;i--) printf "%s ", $i;print ""}'  | sed -r 's/[^ ]*/TEST/4g' |  awk '{for(i=NF;i>=1;i--) printf "%s ", $i;print ""}'
```

Also maybe there is option to change ranges of occurence like 3-5, 6-12, ...?

Example input is:

> one two three four five six seven
>
> eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen
>
> fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty twenty-one

Comment: awk is better for this, you'll not understand a cryptic sed command six monts after writing it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155810

Comment: That answer won't work as here, the searched text is not static. There are other answers there that might fit here, though.

Comment: @CorentinLimier I know this option, this will work only for the same word :)

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but you can simplify your code using `rev` : `echo one two three four five six seven | rev | sed 's/[^ ]*/TSET/4g' | rev` . I'm trying to find a better one as the sed command must be updated if the line contains a different number of words.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: It seems to work with GNU `sed`, but you cannot do the ranges: `sed 's/[^ ][^ ]*/\n&/g;:t;/\n/{x;/.\{4\}/!{s/$/./;x;s/\n[^ ][^ ]*/TEST/;bt};x};s/\n//g' <<< "one two three four five six seven"`

Comment: A simple way to change the first four strings on a line is to add markers to those strings you want to replace e.g. `sed 's/\S\+/\n&/g;s/\n//5g;s/\n\S\+/TEST/g' file` ranges on a line can be achieved using a similar method.

Comment: @potong - worth an answer.  I wasn't seeing how you got to ranges that way, but you just have to add the lower limit to the first replacement.  Neat.  This also gets points for having the string `TEST` there just once.

Comment: @potong nice :) so far best for me.

Answer (score 3):

What about a single **AWK**:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i<5){$i="TEST"}; print}'
```

Test run:

```
$ echo one two three four five six seven | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i<5){$i="TEST"}; print}'
TEST TEST TEST TEST five six seven
```

This solution is short, readable and maintainable. If it does not satisfy you, please add some details about your specific problem.

---

**Perl** equivalent solution:

```
perl -pe 's/\S+/$i++<4?"TEST":$&/ge'
```

Test run:

```
$ echo one two three four five six seven | perl -pe 's/\S+/$i++<4?"TEST":$&/ge'
TEST TEST TEST TEST five six seven
```

---

> maybe there is option to change ranges of occurence like 3-5, 6-12

**AWK:**

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<6;i++)$i="TEST";print}'
```

Test run on the newly provided input file:

```
$ awk '{for(i=3;i<6;i++)$i="TEST";print}' input
one two TEST TEST TEST six seven
eight nine TEST TEST TEST thirteen fourteen
fifteen sixteen TEST TEST TEST twenty twenty-one
```

**Perl:**

```
perl -pe 's/\S+/++$c~~[3..5]?"TEST":$&/ge'
```

Test run on the newly provided input file:

```
$ perl -pe '$c=0;s/\S+/++$c~~[3..5]?"TEST":$&/ge' input
Smartmatch is experimental at -e line 1. <== This is a warning that goes to STDERR
one two TEST TEST TEST six seven
eight nine TEST TEST TEST thirteen fourteen
fifteen sixteen TEST TEST TEST twenty twenty-one
```

Comment: This is ok, but I'm searching for something based on SED if this is even possible and quite easy to implement and remember.

Comment: @mike Yes, you made it clear that youì're looking for a simple only sed solution. I was wondering whether it's just for the sake of learning sed (in which case "not possible" could be an answer) or there are some requirements imposed by the problem at hand (in which case providing a little more context could yield better answers).

Comment: @mike with sed anything other than `s/old/new/` will not be `quite easy to implement and remember.` it will instead be a nightmarish collection of runes that will leave you whimpering in your sleep when you come across it in your code 6 months later and need to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155931/279389) by [mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv). **NOTE**: if you want to process a range, you need to use the maximum bound, as it will process as many matches as it can without throwing any exceptions/errors.

GNU sed:

```
echo 'one two three four five six seven' | \
  sed 's/[^[:space:]]*/\n&/g;:t;/\n/{x;/.\{4\}/!{s/$/./;x;s/\n[^[:space:]]*/TEST/;bt};x};s/\n//g'
```

POSIX sed:

```
nl='
';
echo 'one two three four five six seven' | sed "s/[^[:space:]]*/\\$nl&/g;:t${nl}/\n/{x;/.\{4\}/!{${nl}s/$/./;x;s/\n[^[:space:]]*/TEST/;bt$nl};x$nl};s/\n//g"
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/KhmSu4).

Original explanation (note that here, `1` is replaced with `2`, you may use any other patterns):

> There I use two notable techniques. In the first place every
>   occurrence of `1` on a line is replaced with `\n1`. In this way, as I
>   do the recursive replacements next, I can be sure not to replace the
>   occurrence twice *if* my replacement string contains my replace
>   string. For example, if I replace `he` with `hey` it will still work.
>
> I do this like:
>
> ```
> s/1/\
> &/g
> ```
>
> Secondly, I am counting the replacements by adding a character to
>   `h`old space for each occurrence. Once I reach three no more occur. If
>   you apply this to your data and change the `\{3\}` to the total
>   replacements you desire and the `/\n1/` addresses to whatever you mean
>   to replace, you should replace only as many as you wish.

Comment: Yes, I had thought about this but then I reread the OP looking for something that is not *long and complex* and ditched the idea. Having to choose between the two equally unexplained requirements of *simple* and *sed*, I went with the first and dropped the second. This is however a great excercise for learning sed, it that's the goal.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed working but very complex, I thought that there is way to make this case easy to implement and understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely inappropriate task for sed as sed is for doing simple `s/old/new/` on individual strings, **that is all**. With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ echo one two three four five six seven | awk '{for (i=1; i<=4; i++) $i="TEST"}1'
TEST TEST TEST TEST five six seven

$ echo one two three four five six seven | awk '{for (i=3; i<=5; i++) $i="TEST"}1'
one two TEST TEST TEST six seven
```

and if you need to parameterize it:

```
echo one two three four five six seven |
    awk -v beg=3 -v end=5 '{for (i=beg; i<=end; i++) $i="TEST"}1'
one two TEST TEST TEST six seven
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "one two three four fix six" | \
sed -E ':r s/(^|(TEST )+)[^ ]*/\1TEST/;/^(TEST ){4}/!br'
TEST TEST TEST TEST fix six
```

Explanation:

- `:r` label named r to branch back to
- `s/(^|(TEST )+)[^ ]*/\1TEST/;` replacement that replaces *just one* occurrence of a non-TEST word, preceeded by either the start of the line or 1 or more TESTs
- `/^(TEST ){4}/!br'` regex for what's wanted, followed by the `!br` to branch back to `:r` if it's not matched yet.

Clearly this is fragile.  It will loop infinitely if any lines don't have four words.  Might be GNU sed only.

Comment: What this character "|" does after "^"?

Comment: Within parentheses, a vertical bar is an 'or.'  `(alice|bob)` matches either word.  The `^|` might look like two logical operators, but it's `^` to match the start of the pattern space, followed by an or.